# $\lim_{x→-∞} λ \frac{e^{-x/a}}x , \quad a, λ>0$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x→-∞} λ \frac{e^{-x/a}}x , \quad a, λ>0$$

I believe the answer is minus infinity, but I'm not sure how to explain. The only way I can think of is by explaining that $e^{-x/a}$ grows faster than $x$.
Can you show me pure way to get to the answer?

Comment: I have edited your question to make the mathematics more readable. For next time, please follow [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to properly format mathematics on this site.

Comment: If you have l'Hopital's Rule available, the answer follows almost immediately from applying it.

Comment: Did you have taylors series? You can use it here

Comment: Hint: for all $a,b > 0$ we have $x^{a} = o(e^{bx})$ as $x \to \infty$. A proof of this statement can be found at this S.E..

Answer (score 2):

I will look at
$\lim_{x→-∞}  \frac{e^{-x/a}}x , \quad a > 0$
since
$\lambda$
does not matter.

$\lim_{x→-∞}  \frac{e^{-x/a}}x
=\lim_{x→∞}  -\frac{e^{x/a}}x
$.

From the power series
for $e^x$,
for $x > 0$,
$e^x
=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+....
> \frac{x^2}{2}
$
so
$\frac{e^{x/a}}x
>\frac{\frac{(x/a)^2}{2}}x
=\frac{x}{2a^2}
\to \infty
$
so the limit is
$-\infty$.

Comment: i didn't understand this part in your explanation : " From the power series for e^x, for x>0, e^x=1+x+x^2/2+....>x^2/2".